# How to correctly type-annotate functions with variable types?

Tags: python, python-typing

I'm trying to add type hints to a file system related library, where a lot of functions take a path that is either of `str` or `bytes` type. I can handle my own functions by using overloads, but I'm struggling to handle simple operations or standard library functions that are called inside with arguments of either type. Here is a simplified example:

```py
@overload
def join_paths(s1: str, s2: str) -> str: ...


@overload
def join_paths(s1: bytes, s2: bytes) -> bytes: ...


def join_paths(s1: Union[str, bytes],
               s2: Union[str, bytes]) -> Union[str, bytes]:
    return s1 + s2
```

The overloads work fine if I want to call this function from elsewhere, but my problem is with the `s1 + s2` statement, which causes `mypy` to issue the warnings:

```
example.py:74: error: Unsupported operand types for + ("str" and "bytes")  [operator]
example.py:74: error: Unsupported operand types for + ("bytes" and "str")  [operator]
```

What I want to express is that either both operands are of type `str` or both are of `bytes` type, similar to what is done to my own function using the overloads.

I don't have much experience with typing, so I may just miss the obvious solution, but so far I haven't found how to adapt this to avoid the warnings.

Comment: check this [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/operator-overloading-in-python/)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use a `TypeVar`:

```
from typing import TypeVar

T = TypeVar('T', str, bytes)


def join_paths(s1: T, s2: T) -> T:
    return s1 + s2


join_paths("foo", "bar")    # fine
join_paths(b"foo", b"bar")  # fine
join_paths(1, 2)            # error: T can't be int
join_paths("foo", b"bar")   # error: T can't be object
```

Overloading is more of a tool of last resort when you can't express type relationships via TypeVars and Generics -- using overloads effectively usually involves a lot of runtime type assertions (or `#type: ignore`s) in the body of a loosely-typed implementation.

Comment: You can also use [AnyStr](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.AnyStr)

Answer (score 2):

[typing.AnyStr](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.AnyStr) is the best fit for this specific case.

From the documentation:

> It is meant to be used for functions that may accept any kind of string without allowing different kinds of strings to mix. For example:

```
def concat(a: AnyStr, b: AnyStr) -> AnyStr:
    return a + b

concat(u"foo", u"bar")  # Ok, output has type 'unicode'
concat(b"foo", b"bar")  # Ok, output has type 'bytes'
concat(u"foo", b"bar")  # Error, cannot mix unicode and bytes
```

Therefore, you can modify your code as such:

```
from typing import AnyStr


def join_paths(s1: AnyStr, s2: AnyStr) -> AnyStr:
    return s1 + s2

join_paths("s1", "s2")  # OK
join_paths(b"s1", b"s2")  # OK
join_paths("s1", b"s2")  # error: Value of type variable "AnyStr" of "join_paths" cannot be "object"
```